# Why I am unable to get email-id from Google plus api with angular-google-plus module?

Tags: angularjs, google-plus

The code below is written to be get loggedIn with angular-google-plus module.I am getting user info in response like last name,name,username,image except emailId.

```
  GooglePlus.login().then(function(response) {
    GooglePlus.getUser().then(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
     });
  },
  function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
 };
```

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: No,not yet..Do u hve any idea hw to get it?

Comment: go to the following link you'll find the same code m using.http://plnkr.co/edit/jvHVtNedJoPcqRKg8OLz?p=preview

Comment: You have to provide client ID and api key as well from google developer console.

Comment: @Deepika https://github.com/zephinzer/angular-google-plus/blob/9cdb8bd1c2de59de4bfe0bdc79d3e18db44fdc1c/src/angular-google-plus.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this
  GooglePlus.getProfile().then(function (user) {
                console.log(user);});

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the email id after adding this:

`GooglePlusProvider.setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');`

before

`GooglePlusProvider.init`

This is working for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>DOM Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrzmyr/angular-google-plus/master/dist/angular-google-plus.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var app = angular.module('app', ['googleplus']);

    app.config(['GooglePlusProvider', function(GooglePlusProvider) {
      GooglePlusProvider.setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');

         GooglePlusProvider.init({
           clientId: 'give client id here',
           apiKey: 'give client id here'
         });
    }]);

    app.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', 'GooglePlus', function ($scope, GooglePlus) {
        $scope.login = function () {
          GooglePlus.login().then(function (authResult) {
              console.log(authResult);

              GooglePlus.getUser().then(function (user) {
                  console.log(user);
              });
          }, function (err) {
              console.log(err);
          });
        };
    }])
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="login()">Login with Google Plus</a>
  </body>

</html>
```